# Excel VBA UDF to add prefix to each Character in a string

Tags: excel, vba

I Looking for a way to have a UDF that I can put a cell referance in that will add a prefix of "_" underscore before each character.

eg "TEST" in a cell the UDF result would be "_T_E_S_T"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one simply way can be

```
Function addUndescore(c As range)
Dim x As String
x = "_" & Mid(c, 1, 1)
For i = 2 To Len(c)
    x = x & "_" & Mid(c, i, 1)
    Next i
    addUndescore = x
End Function
```

use with formula =addUndescore(your ref cell)

Comment: almost perfect only issue is that it doesnt add an "_" on the very first character.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Public Function UnderScore(sIN As String) As String
   Dim i As Long
   UnderScore = ""
   For i = 1 To Len(sIN)
      UnderScore = UnderScore & "_" & Mid(sIN, i, 1)
   Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different version: allows the user to optionally change the prefix so that
AddPrefix("TEST") returns "_T_E_S_T" but
AddPrefix("TEST","/") returns "/T/E/S/T"

```
Function AddPrefix(text As String, Optional prefix As Variant) As String
    If IsMissing(prefix) Then prefix = "_"
    Dim s As String, i As Long, n As Long
    n = Len(text)
    s = ""
    For i = 1 To n
        s = s & prefix & Mid(text, i, 1)
    Next i
    AddPrefix = s
End Function
```

Comment: Or: `Optional prefix As String = "_"`